# jquery select class within svg

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a path element within svg

```
<svg ............>
   <........>
   <path fill="#00000" class="abc"></path>

</svg>
```

I am trying to modify the fill attribute with jquery but failed

basically these just don't work

```
$(".abc").css({"fill":"#999999"});
$("svg").find(".abc").css({"fill":"#999999"});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I even tried this https://github.com/RedBrainLabs/jquery.wrap-svg, but still not work

Comment: Nobody know this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to change is an **attribute**, not a style setting. That means you need to use `$.attr()`, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rxuL48sn/2/

JS:

```
$("svg").find(".abc").attr({
  "fill": "green"
});
```

Comment: Please provide a demo where it's broken. As you can see, my demo works :)